# Worklight 6.1 authenticated push to MPNS error http instead of https

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, mpns

we are trying to get authenticated push to windows phone working. Keystore and configuration is done, however when trying to send the push we receive the following error in the log:

```
SEVERE: FWLSE0170E: Notification through Microsoft Push Notification Service (MPNS) was not sent to application myApp-windowsphone8-1.3, because the notification channel that MPNS returned is not a secure uniform resource identifier (URI) (http://s.notify.live.net/u/1/db3/HmQAAACXKSe....wYet/J...0/f...q-a...A/9L_...-fw5zixLg).
000000c5 com.worklight.integration.notification.mpns.MPNSSender       E FWLSE0170E: Notification through Microsoft Push Notification Service (MPNS) was not sent to application myApp-windowsphone8-1.3, because the notification channel that MPNS returned is not a secure uniform resource identifier (URI)
```

How do I get this piece of software to use HTTPS?

Thanks!

edit: here the application-descriptor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
         5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2006, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
         US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
         disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp. --><!-- Attribute "id" must be identical to application folder name --><application xmlns="http://www.worklight.com/application-descriptor" id="myAPP" platformVersion="6.1.0.01.20140518-1532">
<displayName>xxx yyy App</displayName>
<description>xxx yyy App</description>
<author>
    <name>xxx yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</name>
    <email>xxx.yyyyyyyyyyy@xxx.com</email>
    <homepage>http:/xxxxxxx.org/</homepage>
    <copyright>Copyright xxx yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</copyright>
</author>
<mainFile>index.html</mainFile>
<features/>
<thumbnailImage>common/images/thumbnail.png</thumbnailImage>
<iphone bundleId="cc.xxx.myAPP" version="1.3">
    <worklightSettings include="false"/>
    <pushSender password="*********"/>
    <security>
        <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
        <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
    </security>
</iphone>
<android version="1.3">
    <skins>
        <skin name="default">
            <folder name="common"/>
            <folder name="android"/>
        </skin>
        <skin name="android.tablet">
            <folder name="common"/>
            <folder name="android"/>
            <folder name="android.tablet"/>
        </skin>
    </skins>
    <worklightSettings include="false"/>
    <pushSender key="****************-**********************" senderId="nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn"/>
    <security>
        <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
        <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
        <publicSigningKey>Replace this text with the actual public signing key of the certificate used to sign the APK, available by using the 'Extract public signing key' wizard.</publicSigningKey>
    </security>
</android>
<windowsPhone8 version="1.3">
    <uuid*****************-****-****-****-******************</uuid>
    <pushSender>
        <authenticatedPush serviceName="mobile.xxx.zz.cc" keyAlias="mobile_key" keyAliasPassword="**********" ></authenticatedPush>
    </pushSender>
</windowsPhone8>
<windows8 version="1.2">
    <uuid>**********-*****-******-***********</uuid>
</windows8>
```

Comment: Can you paste to the question your application-descriptor.xml? to see if you have entered all required details.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not enough to see where is the problem; can you create a sample application that will show only the issue you are experiencing (w/out any confidential app stuff), so it could be debugged?

Comment: Is there a way to enable some trace or full debug logging on worklight to get you the details? @IdanAdar

Comment: @jerrVienna, is this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Push for Windows does not support proxy or socks. We are moving the nic to direct internet connection.